# How can I use mapStruct for a PatchMapping?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I would like to know can I ignore null fields and convert only the attributes that I put in request

My entity:

```
public class Entity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

My DTO:

```
public class EntityDTO {
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

My Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EntityMapper {

    @BeanMapping(nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ON_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION)
    Entity toEntity(EntityDTO entityDTO);
}
```

My Generated code:

```
@Component
public class EntityMapperImpl implements EntityMapper {

    @Override
    public Entity toEntity(EntityDTO entityDTO) {
        if (entityDTO == null) {
            return null;
        }

        EntityBuilder entity = Entity.builder();

        entity.name(tipoOperacaoParcialUpdate.getName());
        entity.description(tipoOperacaoParcialUpdate.getDescription());
        
        return entity.build();
    }
}
```

I would like a generated code like this:

```
@Component
public class EntityMapperImpl implements EntityMapper {

    @Override
    public Entity toEntity(EntityDTO entityDTO) {
        if ( entityDTO.getName() != null ) {
            entityDTO.setName(entityDTO.getName());
        }
        if ( entityDTO.getDescription() != null ) {
            entityDTO.setDescription(entityDTO.getDescription());
        }

        EntityBuilder entity = Entity.builder();

        entity.name( entityDTO.getName());
        entity.description( entityDTO.getDescription());
        return entity.build();
    }
}
```

I would like a thing like that, how can I do this using mapStruct?

Thank you!

Comment: The code that you like to be generated can throw NullPointerException(if entityDto is null).
Other than that it just contains extra and non required lines of code, which will perform exactly the same functionality as compared to the auto generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [Updating existing bean instances](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances).

e.q.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EntityMapper {

    Entity updateEntity(@MappingTarget Entity entity, EntityDTO dto);
}
```

Which will generate something like:

```
@Component
public class EntityMapperImpl implements EntityMapper {

    @Override
    public Entity updateEntity(Entity entity, EntityDTO dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        if ( dto.getName() != null ) {
            entity.setName(dto.getName());
        } else {
            entity.setName( null );
        }

        if ( dto.getDescription() != null ) {
            entity.setDescription(dto.getDescription());
        } else {
            entity.setDescription( null );
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

In case you want to avoid the setting to null you can use `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy#IGNORE`

Comment: In my case I had to annotate the method with `@BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)`